# 'ModuleNotFoundError' after installing the packages

Tags: python, cmd, pip

I am using a module for a work called cryptography and tried to install it via:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>python -m pip install cryptography
```

Here is a copy of the cmd window:

```
Collecting cryptography

  Using cached cryptography-3.2-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (1.3 MB)

Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.4.1 in c:\users\administrator\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from cryptography) (1.15.0)

Requirement already satisfied: cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8 in c:\program files (x86)\python38\lib\site-packages (from cryptography) (1.14.3)

Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\program files (x86)\python38\lib\site-packages (from cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8->cryptography) (2.20)

Installing collected packages: cryptography
Successfully installed cryptography-3.2
```

Then when I tried using the program it just did not work:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ape esse\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'
```

It gives the same error, as if not installed, and I don't know what to do.

One of my friends said it was a problem with my `python` installation but I've already repaired and reinstalled it and it still gives the same error.

Comment: Does `python main.py` give a different result? Seems like you could have two different installs of python.

Comment: sadly no it gives the same result

Comment: do you have more than one python installed, what happens when you type "where python"?

Answer (score 0):

I installed it now using
`pip install cryptography --no-cache-dir` and it worked perfectly fine on python 3.8.5.
so you might want to try it.

Comment: Used the command you provided me, still the same error.

Comment: what about when you type "where python" what is the output?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38\python.exe

Comment: do you have windows 32bit or 64?